# Using CSVHelper library for C# and handling bad data

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I am using `CSVHelper` library for C# to read a CSV file and convert it to `List<Model>` but there is some bad data in my CSV and I want my code to handle. For example, I want `Decimal` to be converted to 0 if they are `null` or an empty string, so I wrote a custom type converter but the line of code never runs when I debug the code. The reason I am asking this is that I have integers, doubles and in this case decimal that are either "null" or empty string

Custom type convertor:

```
// even if I use DecimalConverter ConvertFromString method never runs
public class TestConverter : DefaultTypeConverter 
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        // this line of code never runs but it should?!
        // I want to check if text is empty string or null then
        // use default value instead but this line of code never runs.
        return base.ConvertToString(text, null, memberMapData);
    }
}
```

Mapper class:

```
public sealed class IndiceMapper : ClassMap<Indice>
{
    public IndiceMapper()
    {
        var headerDictionary = typeof(Indice)
            .GetProperties()
            .ToDictionary(a => a.Name, a => a
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false)
                .Cast<DisplayAttribute>().Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault());

        AutoMap();

        foreach (var (propertyName, displayName) in headerDictionary)
        {
            var p = typeof(Indice).GetProperty(propertyName);

            Map(x => p).Name(displayName, propertyName).TypeConverter<TestConverter>();
        }
    }
}
```

Reader:

```
var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader);
csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
csvReader.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null;
csvReader.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null;

csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<IndiceMapper>();
```

Exception:

```
CsvHelper.TypeConversion.TypeConverterException : The conversion cannot be performed.
    Text: ''
    MemberType: System.Decimal
```

Comment: i'm having this problem! did you ever find a solution? it's driving me insane

Comment: Yes. I ended up creating a new class with all the properties that I want to be more flexible `String` and then used `AutoMapper` to convert object of that temporary class to my actual class. Basically I created a new class called `RawIndice` with most properties `String` and then AutoMapper object of class `RawIndice` to `Indice`